# How to unlock user account in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

One of user name tried login many times and failed. Sql server 2005 locked account automatically. How can I unlock user account in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

Comment: Better question for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 7):

[Bug via SSMS in SQL 2005. Only SQL 2008](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124779)

I assume you know the password or can reset it. From BOL, [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828(SQL.90).aspx)

```
ALTER LOGIN foo WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' UNLOCK
```

Answer (score 3):

Tip/workaround from http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/07/21/unlock-sql-user-without-changing-the-password/#ixzz2OBIJCsqv

```
ALTER LOGIN sqluser WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
ALTER LOGIN sqluser WITH CHECK_POLICY = ON;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Server Management Studio, connect to the server and go to the Security --> Logins item in Object Explorer.  Select the login that is locked out and double-click on it.  The Status page should let you re-enable the login (uncheck the "Login is locked out" box).